# Bash script fails with spaces in path names

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a shell script I'd like to run, but it fails in accessing the external drive path with spaces. I'm not sure which escaping characters to use here. I've tried hard escape \ and quotes. The error I get is:

```
ls: /Volumes/G-DRIVE: No such file or directory
ls: R-Series/Sentinel-1/path_82_frame_648_example/*.zip: No such file or directory
ls: SSD: No such file or directory
ls: mobile: No such file or directory
```

The original script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
Path_S1=/Volumes/'G-DRIVE mobile SSD R-Series'/Sentinel-1/path_82_frame_648_example/   
Path_sub=/Volumes/'G-DRIVE mobile SSD R-Series'/Sentinel-1/path_82_frame_648_sub/   

oldEnd=.zip
newEnd=subset_Orb

for i in $(ls -d -l $Path_S1$S1*.zip)
do
n=${i%.*}
n=${i%T*}
n=${n#"${n%_*}_"}

date
/Applications/snap/bin/gpt /Users/brbell01/Documents/SNAP/subset_and_update_orbits_gpt.xml -Pinput1=$i -Poutput1="$Path_sub$n$newEnd"
date

done
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the series of `n=...` statements. Show a typical filename, and the substring you're trying to extract from it.

Comment: BTW, parameter expansions cannot be nested

Comment: addressing just the error message, wrap variable reference in double quotes, eg: `ls -d -l "${Path_S1}"$S1*.zip`, and if `$S` (`$S1` ??)  can contain white space: `ls -d -l "${Path_S1}${S}"1*.zip`

Comment: @Cyrus  shellcheck.net is great resource. Thanks!

Comment: "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161024T081227_20161024T081251_013629_015D6F_3219.zip" is a typical filename and I just need the date string "20161024".

Answer (score 1):

The main problems:

- unquoted variables
- trying to parse `ls` ==> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

A bit of a rewrite for readability:

```sh
PATH="/Applications/snap/bin:$PATH"

root='/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile SSD R-Series/Sentinel-1'
Path_S1="$root/path_82_frame_648_example"
Path_sub="$root/path_82_frame_648_sub"

data=/Users/brbell01/Documents/SNAP/subset_and_update_orbits_gpt.xml
oldEnd=.zip
newEnd=subset_Orb

for zip in "$Path_S1"/*"$oldEnd"    # don't quote the wildcard
do
    # do something here to extract $n

    date
    gpt "$data" -Pinput1="$zip" -Poutput1="$Path_sub/${n}$newEnd"
    date
done
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn Jackman for your answer. Are double quotes and single quotes functionally equivalent?  I'm still getting an error: `Error: [NodeId: Read] Specified 'file' [input1] does not exist`

Comment: They are not. See [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the manual.